# Error C++ for windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have a question: i'm bussy with compiling , whas clicking on BUILD en then BUILD all after that i get this one

`Error 1   error C3859: virtual memory range for PCH exceeded; please recompile with a command line option of '-Zm176' or greater`

`Error 2   error C1076: compiler limit : internal heap limit reached; use /Zm to specify a higher limit`

`Error 3   error C3859: virtual memory range for PCH exceeded; please recompile with a command line option of '-Zm197' or greater`

[Picto of the error](http://nl.tinypic.com/usermedia.php?uo=adkBqYNLltuaQnhT49YoNoh4l5k2TGxc#.U8hSRmcU-Uk)

PS. i'll try everything with /Zm200 till 2000 nothing work

Comment: I don't see an error in your question. There's a link, but I won't be clicking on it any time soon. Please edit your question to ensure all the relevant detail is on this site. Please also consider ensuring that the spell checking option is enabled on your browser.

Comment: You really ought to copy the text for those errors into your question

Comment: it makes your question more easy to Google, and potential answeres will have more patience with you

Answer (score 5):

This is a common problem when project tend to grow, over and over time, PCH stand for Pre Compiled Headers, this are the files that VC++ compiler create when creating the precompiled headers and latter use for compile the other compilation units.

This file size has a default limit, that you hit, the error line say the fix, using compiler flag /Zm ([Microsoft Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdscwf1c.aspx)) to override the default limit (this option is an scale factor) that mean that /Zm100 is the default limit, /Zm200 is double of the default limit, and so...

The memory necessary for compile any project vary a little from compilation to compilation, i recommend you set the option to some value higher that needed (maybe no much higher), and schedule time for check the precompiled headers (are really precompiled header? (with very large use in the project and little change in the source), are really even used?, can be split in multiple precompiled headers?, etc...). A note here, one compilation unit only can have 1 precompiled header.

To set the compiler config in Visual Studio, go to *Project Properties* -> *Configuration Properties* -> *C\C++* -> *Command Line* and add the config **/ZmXXX** (ex /Zm250).

Comment: Many thxsfor the info i did add /Zm250 on game,scripts,worldserver and i did do build_all and i dident get anny error's